# What Is the maximum - Minimum Size of bat player Can use In cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

What Is the maximum - Minimum Size of bat which player Can use In cricket. Many Players use small bats and other types like different sizes at different time and situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Law 5, The Bat](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-bat):

> 5.7 Bat size limits
>
> 5.7.1 The overall length of the bat, when the lower portion of the handle is inserted, shall not be more than 38 in/96.52 cm.
>
> 5.7.2 The blade of the bat shall not exceed the following dimensions:
>
> Width: 4.25in / 10.8 cm
>
> Depth: 2.64in / 6.7 cm
>
> Edges: 1.56in / 4.0cm.
>
> Furthermore, it should also be able to pass through a bat gauge as described in Appendix B.8.

plus some other minor points about coverings etc. No minimum size is specified.